# Can't use ReposiotryResource endpoint in spring service

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am  using  @RepositoryResource  annotation on my  Reposioptory  interface  with  this  code:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "rest", path = "rest")
public interface HoliDayRepository extends CrudRepository<HoliDayEntity, Integer> {

    HoliDayEntity findOne(Integer id);

}
```

and   i  have  alsoe  added RequestMapping("rest)  in controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class DayController {}
```

but  when i  start  spring  boot  application and  try  this  link  :http://localhost:8080/rest  i  got  404  error  also  while  building application  i  have  ResourceNotFoumd  exceptions   how  should  i  manage  these errors?

Comment: In the [documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/), no controller is created. The idea is that Spring does that for you.

Comment: Hi  @Gimby ,  i  have  tried  this  without  requestMapping  but  the  result  is  the  same  i  can't  got  this  endpoint

Comment: Did you see any initialized url's by Spring MVC during application startup, maybe some prefix added for example `myApp/rest` ??? PS. Try to change log level to find beans and controllers scanning by spring.

Comment: when i   user  culr http://localhost:8080  i  only  got  this  link:{
    "_links": {
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile"
        }
    }
}

Comment: so  there can't  be  any  prefixed  values

Answer (score 0):

with spring boot you don't need to create your own controller; also make sure your web application mapping is different to the one you use for spring data, for example you can set in `application.properties` `spring.data.rest.base-path: /api`

Have a look at this example:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, UUID> {
    List<Person> findByAddress(String address);
}
```

with just this code you should able to access spring data repositories here: http://localhost:8080/api and the person endpoint here http://localhost:8080/api/person

Have a look at this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ or this example: https://github.com/Paizo/SpringBootCamelStreamsExample

Answer (score -2):

You need a method which should be called when you hit your endpoint.

try below and also check spring example:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

```
@Autowired
private HoliDayRepository holiDayRepository; //your repository to execute the query

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")//you can use @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{holida}")
public ResponseEntity<HoliDayEntity > getHolidayById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

    HoliDayEntity holiDayEntityresponse = productOperations.getProductById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(holiDayEntityresponse , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

EDIT:
As pointed by Gimby, this is not applicable when @RepositoryRestResource is used. Both the code and the tutorial attached are refering to creating new REST service by creating the controller

Comment: Note the RepositoryRestResource annotation being used. Your answer would apply if that annotation wasn't used.